# eclipse run web service whereas runnable jar doesn't

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, executable-jar

I have developed a Java application that communicates with a distant web service while also starting a web service to subscribe to notification from the distant host.

It is a blackbox that I do not develop that does all the work therefore I cannot show any meaningful code.

My problem is that when I run my dummy application that wrap this blackbox from eclipse and simply connect to the remote host, it connects perfectly and start the notification webservice, whereas when I export this application into a runnable jar, it does not start the web service listening to the notification port.

Being new to the client/server application, I simply installed Tomcat to be my web server on which the web service should start but unfortunately, this does not work.

Is there something special about eclipse embedded web server that shall allow the web service to start compared to my tomcat?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from a misunderstanding of the external jar I was using. It was it that embedded the soft to start the web service.

It was a depedency issue, now resolved.